# Delete all file in directory older than x days using Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I tried removing the log files with:

```
log 'remove compressed log files'
::Dir['/var/log/*.gz'].each { |f| ::FileUtils.rm_rf(f) }
```

My request is to remove them based to mtime.

Comment: [`File::Stat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File/Stat.html) has methods for this.

Comment: Any what happened when you ran your code? I don't see a question, so what are you asking us?

Comment: It might not be the answer to your question, but maybe to your problem: You are aware of [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) aren't you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just plain Ruby code, not the Chef recipe DSL. A more Chef-ish way to do this would be

```
Dir['/var/log/*.gz'].each do |path|
  file path do
    action :delete
    only_if { ::File.stat(path).ctime < (Time.now - 60*60*24*7) }
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks that really worked. btw, I see the deleted files dumped to /var/chef/backup/home/y/logs/.  Is this the chef way? Can we tell chef to delete permanently.

Comment: Add `backup false` to the resource to disable that behavior. Also it is worth noting that the Dir glob will be expanded at recipe compile time. It doesn't matter much in this case but for other things of this style it won't pick up files added by other Chef recipes because the glob happens "early".